# formula to divide a distance into X parts with incremental step of Y

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I have a mathematical problem that is beyond my ability to solve, so I thought I would ask here:

I have a distance between two values: say 100 and 10. And I have a step value say 5. My need is that I need to reach from 100 to 10 in 5 steps (which is pretty simple). The complexity is that I need an "incremental" step, such that:

step 1 distance < step 2 distance < step 3 distance...so on till the final step. The idea is that each step should be incrementally higher than the previous step. The increment can be something I decide (I dont know how to, thought), but the thing is that there should be a structure to the increment- as in, I cant just randomly keep adding say 10 as first step, 12 as second step, 30 as third step etc.

Can anyone help me formulate something that will help solve this problem I have at hand? Any pointers is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to go about it.  The simplest, IMO, would be to let the first step be $x$, the second $x+d$, the third step $x+d+d$, then $x+d+d+d$, and the fifth step $x+d+d+d+d$.

This means you would have to cover the entire distance in $5x+10d$.  So you set the distance equal to that.  In your example of going from 100 to 10, $$90=5x+10d$$
This gives you multiple ways.  For example, $d=5, x=8$ gives steps of $8,13,18,23,28$

Or $d=1,x=16$ yields $16,17,18,19,20$

Comment: thank you for replying. How do I find the values of x and d? sorry for being so dense...

Comment: There is no single pair of values, there are many.  You can just pick a value for d and then solve for the x that would go with it.  Or pick a value for x and solve the equation for d.  That's what I did for my first set.  I said, let's let d=5.  That gives us $90=5x+50$ or $40=5x$ so $x=8$

Comment: Thanks for that clarification

Comment: Also, another way to do it would be to divide the distance by 15 and call that value x.  And then make your steps have the value of x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x.  So in your case x is $\frac{90}{15}$ so your steps would be 6, 12, 18, 24, 30.  If you're looking for a simple algorithm.

Comment: How did you arrive upon 15 as the value to use to divide? I guess what I am asking is that tomorrow, the 100 to 10 that I have might be any random number like 865 to 23

Comment: If you are dividing it into 5 steps, then 15 will always be the number to use.  It's because it's the 5th triangular number.  1+2+3+4+5=15

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it as 10+(a-2d)+(a-d)+a+(a+d)+(a+2d)=100 to get a=18 therefore you need to take steps of value 18 each but that won't solve your problem it seems like but hold on.

You can use 10+(10+d)+(10+2d)+(10+3d)+(10+4d)+(10+5d)=100 to get d=8/3

So you steps would be of length 38/3,46/3,18,62/3,70/3.
To confirm this is correct
(38+46+54+62+70)3=270/3=90
Hence the solution works.

This answer is a subset of the answer you can find by plotting the graph of
90=5a+10d where a can plotted on the x axis or y and d can be plotted on y axis or x.

Hopes this solves the question

Comment: Thanks. Will this work for any distance? In my case 100 and 10 can change to anything...How do I handle that?

Comment: This will work in all cases since a graph will show you all the possible sets of values of (x,y) for which satisfy the line 90=5x+10y and the solution should be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are familiar with sequences other than the arithmetic sequence, so I hope this helps.
The problem you proposed must satisfy the following equations: 
$$x_0 = 10$$
$$x_1 = x_0 + a_1$$
$$x_2 = x_1 + a_2$$
$$x_3 = x_2 + a_3$$
$$x_4 = x_3 + a_4$$
$$x_5 = x_4 +a_5 = 100$$
$$x_5 = x_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5$$
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 90$$
$$a_1 <  a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < a_5$$
So we can replace the steps by any strictly increasing sequences which satisfy $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 90$. There are many possible sequences which satisfy this.
Here are a few:
$$a_i = 15 + i$$
$$a_i =  (i+1)^2$$
$$a_i = a + d(i-1) $$
The last one is the example given by turkeyhundt. So if you want to find other step sizes, you just have to make sure $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 90, \ \& \ \ a_1 <  a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < a_5$.